# Хотя бы несколько условий в python верны

Tags: python, python-3.x

Условный оператор на python.
Допустим нужно выполнить проверку нескольких условий. Например, a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4. Как сделать на python, чтобы программа выполнялись (например print ("Работает")), если будут верны не все условия, а **хотя бы** 3 из них?

Comment: ну проверьте каждое условие, посчитайте колиство `True`, вот и готово

Answer (score 2):

Пользуемся тем, что `True` это единичка, поэтому проверяем  `sum([a==1,b==2,c==3,d==4])` на нужное число.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос не корректен, не совсем понятно даже, что именно вы хотите. Но предположу, что вам нужно примерно это:

```py
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 5
all_conditions = []
## Каким бы то ни было образом проверяем условия:
all_conditions.append(a==1)
all_conditions.append(b==2)
all_conditions.append(c==3)
all_conditions.append(d==4)
is_true = len(list(filter(None, all_conditions))) >=3
print('Проверка пройдена' if is_true else 'Проверка не пройдена')
```

Вывод:

```bash
Проверка пройдена
```

При изменении пременных:

```py
a = 1
b = 2
c = 100
d = 1000
all_conditions = []
## Каким бы то ни было образом проверяем условия:
all_conditions.append(a==1)
all_conditions.append(b==2)
all_conditions.append(c==3)
all_conditions.append(d==4)
is_true = len(list(filter(None, all_conditions))) >=3
print('Проверка пройдена' if is_true else 'Проверка не пройдена')
```

Вывод:

```bash
Проверка не пройдена
```

Comment: Такая проверка делается в одну строчку, к чему все эти нагромождения...

Comment: Да и сам вопрос не сильно лучше... Но вообще, раз вы знаете, как сделать лучше, предлагаю дать еще один ответ :)

Comment: Я проголосовал за закрытие вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

А если более сложная задача:
Проверка пароля, например (на длину, регистр, наличие цифр и спец. символов). И идет что-то вроде:

```
a = 'gG1'
if len(a) < 5:
print('Пароль должен быть длиннее 5 символов!')
elif a.islower():
print('Должен содержать верхний регистр!')
elif a.isupper():
print('Должен содержать нижний регистр!')
elif a.isalpha():
print('Должен содержать цифры!')
elif '@' not in a:
print('Должен содержать @ или !')
else:
print('Пароль хороший!')
```

Возможно, что сам подход к решению задачи изначально неправильный (но я только учусь и написал как смог). Т.е. на выходе нужно, чтобы пароль нас удовлетворил, если будут удовлетворены хотя бы 3 из 5 условий.

Comment: Если у вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его отдельно с помощью кнопки "Задать вопрос". Если это уточнение к вопросу - добавьте его в сам вопрос, а не в ответ. В ответах должны быть именно ответы на вопрос.